# What's difference between DSLR and bridge camera lenses?

Tags: lens, dslr, bridge-camera

A typical zoom/telephoto lens can cost a lot but a Canon PowerShot SX40 model has a zoom lens of 24-840mm ! And the camera as a whole still costs less than a single lens.

I know that they differ a lot in sensor size, but what are the difference in the lens ? What are the tradeoffs in bridge cameras which allow for such a huge zoom range while still being cost effective ?

Comment: It largely comes back to that tiny sensor -- the smaller the image circle it needs to produce, the easier it is to build a small, cheap lens to cover it (even with a wide zoom range). Even so, the lens is often of somewhat inferior quality.

Comment: Just don't entertain buying a bridge camera... I've never met one yet that produced images I liked.  A high-end compact would even be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the lens in bridge cameras have massive zoom and still cheaper is because it is small compared to a DSLR lens.
The main reason behind this is the sensor size(i.e. crop factor)
The sensor size is a sensor of 6x crop factor. That implies that the image in the P&S sensor is cropped 6 times the image in Full frame sensor. This also can be said as the **zoom in the P&S camera can be 6x at a given focal length** compared to a Full frame camera. 
The Specification 24-840 mm focal length of P&S is Full frame equivalent of the P&S lens.
So, the **real focal length of the given P&S lens is 3-140 mm** lens. Now you can anticipate how small really the 35x zoom on a P&S shoot compared to the DSLR lens.
This smaller focal length of lens can produce that much magnification in a P&S camera. This is the reason for the Cheap price. 
Also P&S lens are not for professional purpose and hence there may be **some compromise in quality** to bring it to the cheaper price.

Comment: Not to mention the aperture size doesn't get anywhere near wide enough to keep ISOs down in low light or (especially with the small sensor) separate background from foreground subjects.

Comment: **Some compromise in quality** is a massive understatement.  Those compact cameras have a sensor that is 1/6 the size in both directions, so 1/36 the amount of light gathering capability, coupled with a resolution that's too high to match the resolvability of its lens.  Low light shots will be a noisy, blurry, muddy mess in comparison to a DSLR.  Even well lit shots won't be as sharp.